# Javascript doesnt work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

Yes, i know this question was asked before but the weird thing in my case it works on one server hosting my site while on the other server it doesnt, 
here it works: http://aspspider.ws/Lordleor/
and here it doesnt: http://www.bookstore.somee.com/

the site is based on general master page,
this is the code i have on my master page(inside the head tag):

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when i check the jscript.js
i see this message:
uncaught type error object has no method draggable, 
any idea how can this be that it's working only on some servers, and how can i repair it to work anywhere?

Comment: Launch chrome and press F12, then browse to the server that doesn't work. Then click on Network tab on developer toolbar, look at Status column. Make sure there are no 404 errors.

Comment: Solved , i put it at each page instead of the master page, thanks for your advices. Yet i dont know why it worked on one server and not on the other.

Answer (score 1):

> uncaught type error object has no method draggable

That's telling you that you don't have a script at `Scripts/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc4.min.js` on the server where there's a problem.

(BTW, 1.6rc4 has been out of date for ***four years***. jQuery UI is currently on v1.10.1, and the v1.8 tree was the gold standard for years.)

Comment: @user1652656: Hence the *"...on the server where there's a problem"* part of the answer.

Comment: @user1652656: And yet, one of them is being served to the client and interpreted properly (on the server where it works), and the other isn't (on the server where it doesn't). That is the problem. Find that problem, and you're all set.

Comment: man, I have no clue what to do here, can you please be more specific? maybe i'm stupid but i have no idea what the reason might be.

Comment: ok, i solved this by puting the script sources at each page instead of the master ones,

Answer (score 0):

I just put it on each page(instead the master) and it worked. Thanks all